# Grails 1.3.7 How to write directly to output stream w/o any buffering

Tags: grails, grails-controller

```
class MyController {
    def startTwoMinuteTask = {
        response.contentType = 'text/html'
        def out = response.outputStream.destination
        out.println 'Starting ...'
        out.flush()
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            out.println " <br>    $i"
            out.flush()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

I'd like this to display 1 through 10 as status updates, alas grails is buffering the the entire thing.  How do I make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the actual answer to your question, but why aren't you using a background Thread?

Using something like the [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) will let you spin off the long-running process.  You can have the browser poll for changes periodically (or using a feature like [Atmosphere](http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere) for push if you can).

The benefit of this is you aren't locking open a connection.  Also, not all browsers will wait that long — sometimes they'll time out.  HTTP isn't really intended as a long-running connection, especially if no information is being passed.